# Button access to public groups

Tags: apex, custom-button, user, button, public-group

I am facing issue to build this logic in my application, can anyone help me how to achieve this scenario.

I have two public groups in my Org like  Group A, Group B.
I have two buttons in the record detail page like Button A, Button B.

Now 1.I need to give access of Button A for Group A users
2. I need to give access to Button A from Group B users and i need to disable the button B for this user group B

Both buttons are custom VF Page buttons .
Can anyone help me , how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Buttons** are part of page layout. Page Layouts are controller by record type and Profiles. Let's ignore record type for now.  Thus if Profile for Group Members of A and B is ame, you won't be be able to achieve this requirement.

Solution: Create 2 profiles, Group A profile and Group B profile. Create 2 Page Layouts- Group A Page Layout and Group B page layout. Assign them accordingly.

Comment: OP has mentioned about VFP buttons

Comment: I read " I have two buttons in the record detail page like Button A, Button B."